# Trouble determining if items should be in view

Tags: logic

I am so stuck on this and it's going to make me go insane trying to figure it out.

Basically I am creating a website that has a slide show. Each slide has an index ranging from 0 to 82. The slide needs to have an infinite scroll but only show 7 slides at a time. I am trying to write a function that I can test against each slide (from 0 - 82) that will output TRUE or FALSE which will determine if that particular index should be in view.

I have a currentIndex variable that I am using such that the "currentIndex" is always the middle slide of the 7. So if he slides that are in view are 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21. 18 would be the currentIndex. As you can imagine, it is easy enough to determine "in view" status with a range like that as I can just take the currentIndex and an offset of 3 to test. For example if I pass the index of 9 into a function called showIndex I could do something like this:

```
function showSlide (index) {
    if (index > (currentSlide - 3) && index < (currentSlide + 3))
}
```

That works great. However, it does not work so great when the "loop" comes around such that the slides being show are supposed to be 81, 82, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 where 1 is the currentSlide.

Attached is an image to give a better representation. Any help would be appreciated. I know this might be more of a code question but the underlying theme seems to be maths and logic. [image]

Answer (score 0):

If $n$ is the number of slides, $i\in\{0,1,\ldots,n-1\}$ is the index to test and $c$ is the current index, then $i$ is visible iff
$$ |c-i|\le 3 \text{ or }|c-i-n| 3\text{ or }|c-i+n|\le 3$$

Comment: Perhaps I am missing something. In the case in my image above where i (one of the indexes to test) is 80, and and 0 is the current index, in your first test 0 - 80 comes to -80 which is less than 3 (test passes), but if the index to test is 79, 0 - 79 is -79, which will pass the test, but it should NOT be in view as it is out of the range as the image illustrates.